# ¿Cómo posicionarse en el final en un archivo binario?

Tags: c++

Tengo esta consigna:

> Escriba una función genérica (template) llamada ampliar() que reciba como
> argumentos un objeto llamado archname de tipo string y un arreglo de la clase vector (STL) llamado x
> que contiene structs de 2 miembros: valor (genérico) y pos (char). El string archname corresponde al
> nombre de un archivo binario. La función debe agregar al archivo el dato (valor) de cada elemento del
> arreglo x. Los agregados se hacen al principio del archivo si pos contiene ‘f’ y al final del archivo si
> pos contiene ‘b’.

Planteé lo siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Tipo {
    T valor;
    char pos;
};

template<typename T>
void ampliar(string archname, vector<Valor>x) {
    fstream arch(archname, ios::binary);
    for(int i = 0; i<x.size(); i++) {
        if(x[i].pos == 'f') {
            arch.seekp(0);
            arch.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x[i].valor), sizeof(x[i].valor));
        } else if(x[i].pos == 'b') {
            /*aquí debería ir al final del archivo*/
            arch.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x[i].valor), sizeof(x[i].valor));
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    return 0;
}
```

Cómo podría ir hacia el final del archivo en ese caso?

Comment: <fstream> tiene métodos para moverte una cantidad definida de posiciones dentro de un arhcivo, te recomiendo revisar esta página https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/

Comment: Estás exhibiendo un [problema XY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_XY), no necesitas posicionarte al principio o al final de un archivo para escribir en el mismo, los archivos no funcionan así. Si quieres "*añadir*" datos a un archivo, debes reescribirlo entero.

Comment: Entonces qué debería hacer, según vos, en esta parte de la consigna? "Los agregados se hacen al principio del archivo si pos contiene ‘f’ y al final del archivo si pos contiene ‘b’.". Sólo lo hice así por esa parte de la consigna.